# C#: Как организовать разные действия у одного нестатического метода, задействуя минимум полиморфизма или не задействуя его вообще

Tags: c#

— Один базовый класс без метода и класс-потомок с методом N, содержащим какое-либо поведение

— Экземпляров класса потомка более 40

— У каждого экземпляра класса-потомка метод N должен содержать разное поведение, определяемое непосредственно этим экземпляром

Грубо говоря:

```
class SomeClass : BaseClass 
{
    public Property1;
    public Property2;
    public Property3;
    public MethodN (...)
    {
        //предположим, что тело метода определяется динамически
    }
}
```

```
var instance1 = SomeClass();
var instance2 = SomeClass();

instance1.MethodN(); //выполнит одно действие
instance2.MethodN(); //выполнит другое
```

И таких instanceX более сорока

В то же время не обязательно, чтобы был всего один метод и всего один класс. В данном случае стоит вопрос "Как это вообще реализовать", а не "Как реализовать таким образом".

Мне нужно, чтобы при вызове метода из экземпляра в этом методе была та совокупность инструкций, которая соответствует данному экземпляру.
Здесь бы подошли наследование и полиморфизм, но загвоздка в количестве таких предметов: их более сорока, соответственно, более сорока разных поведений метода.

В то же время я пытался выполнить подобное по-другому:

1. Создать в классе множество методов (получилось грязно и нагруженно)
2. Создать нестатическое текстовое поле, в которое записывается наименование одного из методов
3. Посредством рефлексии получить из поля метод и вызвать его через делегат

Одно лишь использование рефлексии выдало значительные просадки в производительности, что было дополнено еще и тем, что операции по получению метода выполнялись довольно часто.

Comment: Пример покажите таких методов и классов.

Comment: 1. Если у Вас один и тот-же класс, то каким образом только часть из его экземпляров имеет метод с "поведением"? 2. Если класс один и тот-же, то каким образом поведение метода разнится от экземпляра к экземпляру? Приведите Ваш код или объясните какие задачи и цели у Вас более конкретно.

Comment: _совокупность инструкций_ - покажите эти инструкции.Их четыре десятка или их комбинация даёт столько вариантов?

Comment: Весьма странное усложнение архитектуры

Comment: Наверняка помогут такие паттерны как Стратегия, Состояние, Декоратор.

Comment: @XelaNimed проблема в неправильной первоначальной формулировке. 

1) В данном случае класс еще полноценно не сформирован и находится на уровне концепции, так что обусловимся, что только что на ходу придуман базовый класс без метода и класс-потомок с методом.

2) Класс-потомок один и тот же, но следовало написать не "поведение разнится", а "поведение должно разниться", и именно над этой проблемой я и работаю.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Совокупность инструкций пока отсутствует.
Количество инструкций — четыре десятка и более, они не предназначены для комбинации.

К сожалению, упомянутые паттерны не применимы из-за количества поведений/состояний. Их банально слишком много, чтобы применять данные паттерны.

Comment: А чем конкретно отличаются методы? Чем они манипулируют? Имеется ли общий поведенческий паттерн в работе метода/-ов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В полиморфизме нет ничего плохого, перегружать метод в потомках - отличная практика. Много классов-потомков, у которых тело будет состоять из одной перегруженной функции - не проблема, на мой взгляд.

Но если вы упорно не хотите полиморфизма, можете просто конструктору класса передавать функцию (или делегат это называется что ли в C#), которую класс должен вызывать, и вызывать потом эту функцию в методе класса (если нужно, передавая функции некие параметры состояния класса).

Ещё вариант - сделать одну функцию со switch-ем внутри и при создании экземпляра задавать некий Enum, по которому этот switch будет переключаться при вызове этой функции. Это плохо с точки зрения ООП, но зато классов лишних не будет.

Comment: 1) Я не против полиморфизма, но меня, как человека, не дотягивающего даже до уровня джуниора, сильно смущает целый грузовик из сорока классов, которые разнятся лишь одним перегруженным методом.
2) Я тоже рассматривал вариант использования делегата при создании экземпляра, но и тут есть очередное ограничение: экземпляры создаются не вручную, а искусственно командами SQLite, которые не поддерживают такое комплексное создание экземпляров.
3) Учитывая наличие БД, тогда бы пришлось создавать в ней 40+ таблиц для сопоставления с соответствующими классами

Comment: @Anton Дополнил ответ ещё одним вариантом

Comment: Данный вариант тоже потребляет заметно ресурсов из-за свитча, но не так много, как использование рефлексии. Видимо, с учетом текущих обстоятельств, он выглядит единственным подходящим среди имеющихся. Благодарю

Answer (score 2):

Определим класс следующим образом:

```
class BaseClass { }

class SomeClass : BaseClass
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }

    private readonly Func<int, int, int> _func;

    public SomeClass(Func<int, int, int> func)
    {
        _func = func;
    }

    public int MethodN()
    {
        return _func(Property1, Property2);
    }
}
```

При создании экземпляров передаём в конструктор делегат. Именно он будет реализовать поведение каждого конкретного экземпляра.

Например, `someA` будет складывать значения своих свойств, а `someB` - умножать.

```
var someA = new SomeClass((x, y) => x + y);
someA.Property1 = 2;
someA.Property2 = 3;

var someB = new SomeClass((x, y) => x * y);
someB.Property1 = 2;
someB.Property2 = 3;

Console.WriteLine(someA.MethodN()); // 5
Console.WriteLine(someB.MethodN()); // 6
```

Comment: Увы, тоже не получится подобным образом выполнить: моя первоначальная идея реализации подобного была схожа с вашей, но после потребности в использовании БД её пришлось отложить в долгий ящик, так как создание экземпляров из БД не поддерживает передачу в конструктор делегатов

Comment: @Anton - а каким боком тут БД? Почему про это ни слова в вопросе? | Делегат не обязательно задавать в конструкторе, можно сделать это в свойстве или методе.